# How can I request a new circuit for a site using control commands?

Tags: circuit, firefox

I've recently been trying to set up some basic tor functionality with firefox by routing certain sites through the tor network to allow for more anonymity and the ability to access tor hidden services. An issue I've come across is that, simply running the control command `SIGNAL NEWNYM` to generate a new circuit does not route previously connected websites through the new circuit. Is there a way to request a new circuit for a previously visited website, forget all previous circuits, or do something else to get a new identity for one or all previously visited sites using control commands only?

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct command to request a new circuit for *any* specific purpose due to anonymity - and this is normal. If you are constructing your circuits by hand using Stem library, for example, - then you can control what circuits are made *in common*, but not in particular matter